# Kotlin skip loop iteration

Tags: loops, kotlin

I am writing a Kotlin program and I want to *skip* an iteration of the loop. I know the continue keyword, that jumps to the next interation, but is there a way to elegantly jump to the second next iteration, skipping the next iteration? I would imagine the code to look like this:

```
for(i in 0 until 10){
    if(i == 5){
        skip
    }
    println(i)
}
```

with the result being this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
7
8
9
```

PS: I know how I could do it other ways, but I am asking if there is a very easy or kotlin-native way of doing this.

Comment: How is `skip` more elegant than `continue` aside from using a different word?

Comment: `continue` goes to the next iteration. `skip` would skip the next iteration and continue at the iteration after the next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in a `for` loop, then you can simplify it by using a range and a predicate that removes some values from the loop:

`(0..9).filter { !(it in 5..6) }.forEach { println(it) }`

here `!(it in 5..6)` is the predicate but you can build your own.

Comment: I always prefer `!` before a parenthesis when possible because I think it's more readable. It's a matter of style.